Enable Webhook for Community API
This is probably a lost cause based on other stack overflow threads (albeit not many).
Im creating an application on LinkedIn that integrates with my app. Im using the Community Management API.. One of the features that is of highest value is the Social Action notifications via webhook.
However... it doesn't seem as though I have access to the webhooks tab via the developer portal.. after getting access to the community api.
Based on the docs.. "The Webhooks tab is only enabled for applications with a use case for webhooks". Since one of the biggest features of the community management API makes use of webhooks it seems insane to me that it wouldn't be enabled once access has been granted to this API.
Hopefully someone can help with next steps here and how I can get this enabled.
Cheers
I was expecting the Webhooks tab.
